# Java exception and error handling

Tags: java, error-handling, exception

Programming beginner here, I am having trouble with error/exception handling as I do not have a clue how to do it. For my menu system (code below), I want it to alert users when anything other than 1-6 is entered, is try catch the best method? Can someone show me how it should be implemented?

```
 do
            if (choice == 1) {
                System.out.println("You have chosen to add a book\n");
                addBook();
            }
            ///load add options
            else if (choice == 2) {
                System.out.println("Books available are:\n");
                DisplayAvailableBooks();         //call method
            }
            ////load array of available books
            else if (choice == 3) {
                System.out.println("Books currently out on loan are:\n");
                DisplayLoanedBooks();       //call method
            }
            //display array of borrowed books
            else if (choice == 4) {
                System.out.println("You have chosen to borrow a book\n");
                borrowBook();      //call method
            }
            //enter details of book to borrow plus student details
            else if (choice == 5) {
                System.out.println("What book are you returning?\n");
                returnBook();     //call method
            }
            //ask for title of book being returned
            else if (choice == 6) {
                System.out.println("You have chosen to write details to file\n");
                saveToFile();         //call method
            }

            while (choice != 1 && choice != 2 && choice != 3 && choice != 4 && choice != 5 && choice != 6) ;
            menu();
            keyboard.nextLine();//catches the return character for the next time round the loop
            }
```

Comment: ugh do not chain together so many statements in a while loop

Comment: Invalid input is *not* exceptional behavior. This is normal behavior and should just be handled with regular validation of some sort. Just output a message if the value doesn't fall within the allowable range or is otherwise not an integer.

Comment: Yes, agree with @tnw. I would change the title. Really misleading.

Comment: Invalid input could totally be exceptional behavior. The question is can you recover from the invalid input in the same method and ask for more input. It's completely reasonable to throw an exception in some cases of invalid input. This sitch doesn't seem like such, but don't rule out exceptions completely when you get bad input.

Answer (score 0):

Try a switch statement

```
switch() {
    case 1:
        addBook();
        break;
    // etc ...
    default:
        System.out.println("Not a valid choice");
        break;
}
```

The switch will also work with strings so you can add a **q** to the menu to quit or a **b** to go back to make a multi level menu.

This may be whats needed as all user input from readline is considered a **string** so unless you are converting the input to int, which will need to be wrapped in a try catch, this is the better option as the default will take care of any unexpected user input.

`case "1":` & `case "q":`

Comment: Thanks, I changed to a switch statement! Much better! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

A more "clean" and much more understandable way to write it would be something like this

```
if(choice < 1 || choice > 6) {
    //invalid input handling
}

while (choice >= 1 && choice <=6) {
    // choice handling and program execution
}
```

Another option you can try is use a switch statement which you can study here 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/method_enum.htm

And the other comments are correct, this is not exception handling and rather undesirable input handling. Exception handling would be for example inputing a null and a null exception error is thrown. There you could use a try catch to continue running your program even if an error is thrown.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion